# AngularJS ng-options using all object propertkey

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I like to use the ng-options to create a select element thats have alls propertykeys of an object stored. Without an function will be nice.

```
$scope.dataItem = [
 { firstname: "beate", lastname: "lind" }
 { firstname: "john", lastname: "rich" }
]
```

The select element have to look like these :

```
[-Select--]
[firstname]
[lastname]
```

Comment: You want to have list that contains only keys or its values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have just the keys of an object, you need to supply an object (not an array) to ng-options. For your example above you can do this:

```
ng-options="key for (key, value) in dataItem[0]
```

[Working Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Nl9zW4UH3IafAYXVgmcj?p=preview)